# Created C header file, getting errors

Tags: c, header

I'v created a C header file (It's compiled), now when i compile my program it comes up with tons of errors like:

warning: null character(s) ignored
error: stray ‘\23’ in program
TheFunctions.h:1722: error: stray ‘\200’ in program

Inside the header file is simply two functions, which work in the normal c program.

Please help!

Comment: What software did you use to create the file? Can you show some code?

Comment: GCC on mac os x, written all files on textmate

Comment: I'm guessing there could be some problem with the ' or " or such characters.  Posting the code or its skeleton should help generating better answers.

Comment: I can't really post the code as it contains private data., though its just two functions in there, shouldn't be any errors?

Comment: You don't compile header files so I think we need to know exactly what you are doing. The header is pure text - you compile .c files

Comment: The top of the program .c is // Include required frameworks.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "TheFunctions.h";

Comment: Can you at least post lines 1721 - 1724 of TheFunctions.h

Comment: The max lines are about 200, the file doesn't go that high

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you're trying to directly include a precompiled header (a binary file). When you include files via the `#include` pre-processor statement, those are text files, not compiled files.

**Edit** (now that we know what compiler it is): I don't know GCC's precompiled headers stuff well enough to *answer* this question, but here's a link discussing them for what it's worth: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html

Comment: I'm using GCC & CC on mac os x10.6

Comment: Is it possible to include precompiled headers at all?

Comment: Is it possible to include compiled C Code?

Comment: @Daniel: *"Is it possible to include precompiled headers at all?"* Yes, see the link. Different compilers do it differently. Note that in all implementations I've seen, though, the actual file you're `#include` ing is a *text* file; it's just that (in the GCC case) if you `#include <foo.h>` and you have previously pre-compiled `foo.h`, you'll have a `foo.h.pch` file. The compiler will see that and use it. *"Is it possible to include compiled C Code?"* Normally you compile code as a library, and then *link* with the library (rather than "including" it).